# mac snow leopard setuptools stick to MacOSX10.4u.sdk when trying to install python-mysql

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard, compilation

when I try to install python-mysql today, I got a number of compilation error or complaining /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk not found, like the following:

> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-i386-2.6/MySQLdb
>   running build_ext
>
> building '_mysql' extension
>
> Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
>
> Please check your Xcode installation

However, I already installed latest xcode 4.0, which does include latest GCC and SDK.

I tried to find out where the 10.4u.sdk is specified, but could not find it in the system environment, program source and setuptools source.

I tried to export

> export SDK=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
>
> export SDKROOT=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk

but still has no luck.

so anyone has any idea where this is specified in Mac Snow Leopard pls?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your environment for `CFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`.  Both of these can include the `-isysroot` argument that influences the SDK selection.  The other place to start at is to look at the output of `python2.6-config --cflags --ldflags` since (I believe) that this influences the Makefile generation.  Make sure to run `easy_install` with `--verbose` and see if it yields any additional insight.

Comment: I think u r definitely right about python2.6-config --cflags, however I wonder how might I change that value, thx?

Comment: I believe that you need to recompile python 2.6 with a more recent version of the SDK to change that.  It is set when Python is compiled IIRC.